# How to extend the django admin site

Tags: django

I am using django 1.8 and would like to extend the django admin site. More specifically I want to find where the view, template and url files are for the django admin site. I tried googling around but only found documentation for older versions.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates